# Can`t Permit Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server via database permission

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Can anyone plz explain which special permission require for doing Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server connection via server and client both end.
i have following scenario.

1. server PC With Sql Server 2012 database
2. client PC With Only Program Which will connect database  of server

i successfully got the db connection via visual stdio **sqlconnectin** class of remote database

but when i use **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server** it will thrwo error for permission

can anyone help?

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlconstrbldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString.ToString());
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection();
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server sqlServer = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(sqlconstrbldr.DataSource);
ServerName = sqlconstrbldr.DataSource; 
foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database dbServer in sqlServer.Databases)
{
    if (dbServer.Name.StartsWith("AMCS"))
    {
        string year = dbServer.Name;
        year = year.Substring(4);
        string Fyear = year.Substring(0, 2);
        string Lyear = year.Substring(2);
        Fyear = "20" + Fyear;
        Lyear = "20" + Lyear;
        string dbYear = Fyear + " - " + Lyear;
        cmbDbYear.Items.Add(dbYear);
    }
}
```

Explaination

cmbDbYear is Just Combobox in which all database names will be bonded.

MY Question is That What Remission Needed for SQL Server Management Object (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)  must required for SQL Server Database user to successfully perform operation

i can Do Normal Database Operation currently but want also SQL Server Management Object (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) on database.

Comment: With the same connection string?

Comment: Post the code you're using to connect via SMO

Comment: @JacobH Yaa with same conenction string

Comment: @squillman hear i edited my que with code

Comment: You need to format your question properly, highlight your code and press the `{ }` button on the toolbar. Also things like your numbered lists did not come over too. There is a preview at the bottom of the page when you are editing your question, check that before you submit

Comment: Also your question is [missing the exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) and you don't show where `cmbDbYear` is coming from, none of your code shows how you got that variable.